# Why does getNextZipEntry skip root directory for few files?

Tags: java, file, zip, unzip

Hi when i am trying to unzip my file i am using the following snippet

```
    public static List<String> unZip(File tarFile) throws IOException {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(tarFile);
    ZipArchiveInputStream in = new ZipArchiveInputStream(inputStream);
    ZipArchiveEntry entry = in.getNextZipEntry();
    while (entry != null) {
        System.out.println("Entry name ::: "+entry);
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("This entry is a directory ");
            entry = in.getNextZipEntry();
            continue;
        }
        result.add(entry.getName());
        entry = in.getNextZipEntry();
    }
    in.close();
    return result;
}
```

My above snippet outputs as

```
Entry name ::: lib/docssdk.jar
Entry name ::: lib/jackson-annotations-2.7.4.jar
Entry name ::: lib/jackson-core-2.7.4.jar
Entry name ::: lib/jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar
Entry name ::: lib/jsonapi-converter-0.3.jar
Entry name ::: lib/okhttp-3.0.1.jar
Entry name ::: lib/okio-1.7.0.jar
Entry name ::: lib/retrofit-2.0.2.jar
```

I am expecting it to be as

```
Entry name ::: lib/
Entry name ::: lib/docssdk.jar
Entry name ::: lib/jackson-annotations-2.7.4.jar
Entry name ::: lib/jackson-core-2.7.4.jar
Entry name ::: lib/jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar
Entry name ::: lib/jsonapi-converter-0.3.jar
Entry name ::: lib/okhttp-3.0.1.jar
Entry name ::: lib/okio-1.7.0.jar
Entry name ::: lib/retrofit-2.0.2.jar
```

The root folder lib/ is missing

I am getting the expected ouput when i am unzipping the file content in my machine and created a zip again on lib folder.

Why i am missing my root folder here while obtaining `getNextZipEntry`? Please advice me on this.

I have attached the [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1N73zJVTNRna3ZYamZ0bXFreTg/view?usp=sharing) of the zip structure along with this

[Original Zip File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1N73zJVTNRnOHZ6VVN6aF9Qb0E) to reproduce this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see the `lib/` entry because it doesn't exist in your zip file:

```
$ zipinfo zip_root_folder_issue.zip 
Archive:  zip_root_folder_issue.zip
Zip file size: 1878250 bytes, number of entries: 8
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx    17596 bx defN 16-Aug-02 13:38 lib/docssdk.jar
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx    50897 bx defN 16-Aug-02 13:40 lib/jackson-annotations-2.7.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx   253001 bx defN 16-Aug-02 13:39 lib/jackson-core-2.7.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx  1204187 bx defN 16-Aug-02 13:39 lib/jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx    36004 bx defN 16-Aug-02 13:39 lib/jsonapi-converter-0.3.jar
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx   326467 bx defN 16-Aug-02 13:39 lib/okhttp-3.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx    69868 bx defN 16-Aug-02 13:38 lib/okio-1.7.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx    86225 bx defN 16-Aug-02 13:38 lib/retrofit-2.0.2.jar
8 files, 2044245 bytes uncompressed, 1876818 bytes compressed:  8.2%
```

Archive managers are likely display intermediary "missing" folders but a zip file doesn't need entries for them. Some file format using zip (xlsx for example) even expect to have none of them.

In your case, I think you will need to do what these managers do: show/create the folder if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

@subramanian rasapan, if you wish to only extract the Zip files then I can suggest a 3rd party tool for easiest extraction along with the above issue solved.

The name of the tool is Zip4J : www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php

Just add it to your library and you can use the following code for extraction :

```
public void unZipFile(String filePath) 
    {
        String destination = "<desired-destination>";
        try 
        {
            String zipFileName = new File(filePath).getName();
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(filePath);
            zipFile.extractAll(destination);
        } 
        catch (ZipException e) 
        {
        }
    }
```

For the above code to work you need the following imports :

```
import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;
```

I am providing a Test Program to unzip any zip file :

```
package unzip;

import java.io.File;
import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;


public class Unzip 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String fileName = "abc.zip";
        String destination = "D:\\copiedTo";
        try 
        {
            String zipFileName = new File(fileName).getName();
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(fileName);
            zipFile.extractAll(destination+"\\"+zipFileName);
        } 
        catch (ZipException e) 
        {
        }
    } 
}
```

The extracted file from the Zip file will be saved to d:\copiedto\\.

My zip structure :

```
abc.zip (zip file)
|_abc
  |_1.txt
  |_2.txt
  |_3.txt
  |_4.txt
  |_5.txt
  |_6.txt
```

When extracted the folder is as same structure of the zip file (along with root folder).

I am attaching links of the files I have tested with please check them if necessary:

Zip file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fTzD5zwqL0M1lqM3EwazVzWUE/view?usp=sharing
Extracted File : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4fTzD5zwqL0T0xVaXhmSzZ6VWc

Please check and tell if there is any confusion.
Thanks and Regards.

Comment: I would like to preview my zip file before extraction . For which i would like to extract the exact folder structure within the zip file.